# can not retrieve dynamic table td value using jquery

Tags: jquery, razor

I am trying to get the TD value from a dynamically created table when button is click 
here is my table:

```
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td id="Quantity">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)
        </td>
       <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info btnupdate" onclick="Update(@item.Id);">
               Update
            </button>
        </td>                            
    </tr>
}</tbody>
```

here is my jquery:

```
            function update(id) {

            var Id = id;

            var quantity = $(Quantity).html().trim();//get only first td value for every tr
            var quantity = $(Quantity).text().trim();//get every td value 
            var quantity = $(this).closest("tr").find("#Quantity").text().trim(); //undefined
            var quantity = $('#Quantity').attr("value") //undefined


        }
```

i can't figure out this problem. any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why are you defining `quantity` 4 times? also you are getting multiple ids with `Quantity` an ID shall always be unique

Comment: Ids have to be _unique_

Comment: Id must be unique .

Comment: i define quantity only here . anyway thanks.. i find a solution .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass `item.Quantity` directly which can be accepted as parameter.

```
<button onclick="Update(@item.Id,@item.Quantity);">.....</button>
```

---

However, I would recommend you to use unobtrusive event-handler using `.on(eventType, handler)` method . Assign `@item.Id` to custom `data-*` attribute which can be fetched using `.data(key)`.

Then various DOM traversal methods can be used

```
    <tr>
        <td class="Quantity">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)
        </td>
       <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info btnupdate" data-id="@item.Id" >
               Update
            </button>
        </td>                            
    </tr>
```

*Script*

```
$('.btnupdate').on('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var qty = $(this).closest('tr').find('Quantity').text();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

your `id` to each `td` should be unique and that you can achieve by simply appending the `item.Id`:-

```
<td id="@("quantity" + item.Id)">
```

and then you can access it like you already are doing,

```
function update(id) {
    var quantity = $('#quantity' + id).html().trim();
    alert(quantity);
}
```